# Solspace select options not being stored

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

I am populating a select drop down with custom options in the template, but those options are not being displayed in the individual Form submission page.

Example code below:

```
{% if field.handle == "country" %}            
<div class="fe {{ columnClass }}">
   <label class="select-label">
      <select name="{{ field.handle }}" id="form-input-{{ field.handle }}" required>
          <option value="">Country *</option>
          <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
          <option value="xx">another country...</option>
    </label>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

The Country field handle is `country`

Outputted html is:

```
<div class="fe freeform-column  freeform-column-6">
    <label class="select-label">
        <select name="country" id="form-input-country" required>
            <option value="">Country *</option>
            <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="xx">Another country...</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

When I view the individual submission in admin I see the below:
[image: Form submission page]

But in the submission list page the value does appear:

[image: Submissions List]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is currently a limitation of Freeform. It expects that the option values are predefined for the field, and not dynamically loaded at template level.

It's on our feature requests list to come up with a way to let users override this functionality. :)